# FakeFS and CSV.open spec test raises ArgumentError:wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Tags: ruby, csv, rspec

I have a problem when  spec test CSV.open with fakefs and raises  ArgumentError:        wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

the spec code is as follow :

ruby version is jruby 1.7.1 (1.9.3p327)

fakefs version is 0.4.2

require 'fakefs/safe'

```
 it 'should pull offers and save them into file' do
    FakeFS do 
      extractor.process(affiliate_ids)
      File::size(FILE_NAME).should > 0
    end
  end
```

the ruby code is as follow:

```
class Extractor
  def process(affiliates)
    save(ds)
  end

 # saves all the buy URLs to a text file
  def save(ds)
    @@logger.info "Writing offers to file #{FILE_NAME}"

    CSV.open(FILE_NAME, "w") do |csv|
      ds.each do |row|
        buy_url = row[:buy_url]
        csv << [row[:name], row[:offer_id], buy_url]
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Anyone knows what causes this issue?
Thanks in advance

David Wu

Answer (score 1):

The problem got fixed in JRuby. Check details here. https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs/issues/172

-Alex